# Identify this instrumental electronic and classical music

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, electronic-music, instrumental

I have this instrumental music on my computer, but it has no information attached: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jOXzxlxbMhdEM1YWlxLTRtZTA/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is [*Viva*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_7BhkGcCis) (Orion Mix) by the quartet band [Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_(band)) *that specialises in classical crossover and synth-pop music.*

Like the name suggests, this song is a remixed cover of Vivaldi. This is confirmed on this [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Bond-Viva-Wintersun/release/1687009) page:

> Written by: **Vivaldi**.

The original piece is [*The Four Seasons, Winter, 'Allegro non molto'*](https://youtu.be/XgbkvaLy3Lg?t=73).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the details, but YouTube says it's Vivaldi, and I have no reason to disagree with them. (It's been years since I listened to any Vivaldi, but he had a very specific style he liked -- enough that people like to joke that he wrote the same concerto 500 times -- and the recording you posted definitely has that sound to it.)

It looks like they have another version of this here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nY33BLwZQjQ

Comment: You seem to refer to [Stravinsky](http://www.azquotes.com/quote/1395670) or probably more exact quoted [here](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Antonio_Vivaldi). His statement is by no means undisputed nor funny.

Comment: I stand corrected. It is never funny to mention apochryphal jokes about repetition.  It is never funny to mention apochryphal jokes about repetition.  It is never funny to mention apochryphal jokes about repetition.  It is never funny to mention apochryphal jokes about repetition.  It is never funny to mention apochryphal jokes about repetition ...